# Masking objects behind objects on another render layer

Tags: render-layers, masking

I'm using render layers in my scene to seperate multiple objects for compositing, but want to add them back together afterwards.

For that, I need to a way to hide parts of the volumes on layer 2, that would appear behind objects on layer 1, if they were on the same layer:

Layer 1:
[image: Layer1]
Layer 2:
[image]
For example, the volume lights on the front should be partially hidden, since the Submarine on layer 2 would obscure them, but the light in the back should be fully visible, since it would be in front of the Submarine.
How can I achieve this in Blender?

Older versions seem to have included "mask layers", but I can't seem to find any mention of them from 2.8 and onward...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the "Holdout" restriction toggle in the outliner.
[image]

You're able to enable it on a collection of your choice that will be used to mask anything behind it, but not show up in your render. Simple and effective:

[image]
[image]